# collectd + graphite Disk Writes Cumulative Instead Of Per Time Period

Tags: metrics, graphite, collectd, disk-io

Most of the collectd stats (such as memory free/used, etc) for my hosts display in units per time period on graphite, producing jagged graphs as expected.  However, when I examine metrics from the collectd disk plugin, I see an ever-rising slope of values over time, as if the values were being summed together, as in the image below:

[image: A few days of disk write operations]

When I examine the .conf files for collectd plugins on the host, the relevant one for the disk plugin merely contains 'LoadPlugin 'disk'".  What might prevent my setup from displaying disk statistic graphs like the ones on the [collectd disk plugin wiki](https://collectd.org/wiki/index.php/Plugin:Disk)?

Comment: Wrap your cumulative metric in a derivative() function

Comment: did you look at the **StoreRates** parameter in the *write_graphite* plugin?